# How can I get the datasource of a personalized sublayout (webforms)?

Tags: presentation, caching, datasource, webforms, sublayout

I'm working on enabling sublayout caching for personalized sublayouts.

```
public class ContextCacheableSublayout : Sublayout
{
    public override string GetCacheKey()
    {
        var cacheKey = base.GetCacheKey();
        cacheKey = string.Concat(cacheKey, GetCustomCacheKeyPart());
        return cacheKey;
    }
    private string GetCustomCacheKeyPart()
    {
        //// GET DATASOURCE WITH PERSONALIZATION
    }
}
```

Basically I just need to generate a cache key based on the correct datasource given the personalization rules. I have the Sublayout already, which has `this.Datasource`. But how do I make sure to get the current *personalized* datasource?

I'm following [this post](http://www.sitecorecoding.com/2016/02/caching-rendering-html-when-conditional.html) as a reference but it pertains to MVC, and I'm not sure how to do the same things with webforms

Comment: When does `this.Datasource` get swapped out if personalization occurs? Is it part of the `Sublayout` code? I'm struggling to remember how WebForms work lol!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to trip down memory lane, as it's been a while.

You can try out following code to get the personalized datasource.

```
public static List<Item> GetPersonalizationDataSourceItems(this Item i)
{
     List<Item> list = new List<Item>();
     foreach (RenderingReference reference in i.GetRenderingReferences())
     {
        list.AddRange(reference.GetPersonalizationDataSourceItem());
     }
     return list;
}
```

```
private static List<Item> GetPersonalizationDataSourceItem(this RenderingReference reference)
{
    List<Item> list = new List<Item>();

       if (reference != null && reference.Settings.Rules != null && reference.Settings.Rules.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var r in reference.Settings.Rules.Rules)
                {
                    foreach (var a in r.Actions)
                    {
                        var setDataSourceAction = a as Sitecore.Rules.ConditionalRenderings.SetDataSourceAction<Sitecore.Rules.ConditionalRenderings.ConditionalRenderingsRuleContext>;
                        if (setDataSourceAction != null)
                        {
                            Item dataSourceItem = GetDataSourceItem(setDataSourceAction.DataSource, reference.Database);
                            if (dataSourceItem != null)
                            {
                                list.Add(dataSourceItem);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

       return list;
}
```

Referance link: https://horizontal.blog/2015/09/08/programmatically-get-personalization-datasource-items-of-a-sitecore-item/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Webforms, it's been a while.

```
var renderingReference = Sitecore.Context.Page.GetRenderingReference(this.Parent);
var datasourcePath = renderingReference.Settings.DataSource;
```

As I recall, this is how you get the datasource. The idea being, you get this value. If it's an empty string, you fall back to `Sitecore.Context.Item`.

I didn't just pick this out of my personal memory space, I looked around a bit for a refresher ;-)

Source: https://tangenttechnologies.ca/blog/sitecore-webforms-datasources-and-rendering-parameters/

Comment: Will this get the correct datasource based on the personalization rules though, or the default datasource?

Comment: The current datasource

Comment: Oh well that's simpler than I expected :D thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found an example that is being used to get Personalised datasource from a view rendering. I hope the same logic you can use within your methods.

Here is the sample conde snippet given below.

```
    private static IEnumerable<Item> GetPersonalizationDataSourceItem(RenderingReference reference, Item i)
    {
        var list = new List<Item>();

        //if no datasource
        if (reference == null)
        {
            return list; 
        }

        //else if no Personalisation is used, return the default datasource
        if (reference.Settings.Rules == null || reference.Settings.Rules.Count <= 0)
        {
            var item = GetDataSourceItem(reference);
            if (item != null)
            {
                list.Add(item);
            }
            return list; 
        }

        var ruleContext = new ConditionalRenderingsRuleContext(new List<RenderingReference> {reference}, reference)
        {
            Item = i
        };

        reference.Settings.Rules.RunFirstMatching(ruleContext);
        list.Add(GetDataSourceItem(reference.Settings.DataSource, reference.Database));

        return list;
    }
```

And you can follow the below link to get the whole source code.

https://gist.github.com/blacktambourine/9573265cec679134128c7e628f7aff0b